# Python: Making a Flask Rest API Asynchronous and Deploying it

Tags: python, rest, asynchronous, flask

I have a python server that is currently keeping track of the location of all the buses in my university and generating predictions of arrivals to specific locations.

Now, I wanted to attach a lightweight REST API to this server but I have been running intro problems.

I tried using flask with the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from PredictionWrapper import *
import threading

class RequestHandler(): 
    def __init__(self,predictionWrapper):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.predictor = predictionWrapper
        self.app.debug = False
        self.app.add_url_rule('/<route>/<int:busStop>','getSinglePrediction',self.getSinglePrediction)
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.app.run, kwargs={'host':'0.0.0.0', 'port':80, 'threaded':True})
        t.start()

    def getSinglePrediction(self, route, busStop):
         # TODO Get the actual prediction with given parameters
         prediction = self.predictor.getPredictionForStop(route, busStop)
         return jsonify({'busStop': busStop, 'prediction': prediction})


    def getStopPrediction(self, busStop):
         # TODO Get the actual prediction with given parameters
         return jsonify({'busStop': busStop, 'prediction': 2})

    def run(self):
         self.app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, threaded=True)
```

The problem is that I have been encountering the error below after about half a day of running the server. Note that no requests were made to the server around the time it failed with the following error:

ERROR:werkzeug: - - [01/May/2016 09:55:55] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x02\xfd\xb1\xc5!')

After investigating I believe I need to deploy to a WSGI production server. But I have no clue what it means in this specific approach given that 1)the flask server is being threaded in order to run the rest of the prediction application, and 2)I am using classes which none of the documentation uses.

Any help on how to setup the wsgi file with apache, gunicorn, or the technology of your choice would be appreciated. Also, any comments on a better approach on making a non-blocking REST API would be helpful.

Let me know if you need any further clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this can actually solve your problem but you can use the coroutine based web server gevent. They have a WSGI server that you can use if that's what you meant by saying that you need to deploy a WSGI production server.

If you want to implement the server to your flask application just do the following:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
app = Flask(__name__) 
http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Gevent in general is a very powerful tool and by issuing context switches as necessary it can handle multiple clients very easily. Also, gevent fully supports flask.

Comment: This seems like something that could most definitely help. Do you know if you can call serve_forever into new thread?

Comment: Indeed you can, by doing this:
http = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
thread = threading.Thread(target=http.serve_forever)
thread.start()

However, you might need this code to make it work:
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

This is due to gevent removing the automatic monkey patching and and error can be caused by not monkey patching.

"error: cannot switch to a different thread" is the error

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to put exception handling to deal with bad JSON request data (which maybe is what's happening) something like

```
def getSinglePrediction(self, route, busStop):
     try:
         prediction = self.predictor.getPredictionForStop(route, busStop)
         return jsonify({'busStop': busStop, 'prediction': prediction})
     except:
         return jsonify({'busStop': 'error', 'prediction': 'error'})
```

Comment: Okay, added that as a sanity check but the problem is that the error happened at a time when the server was not getting requests (which makes it even more strange)